# JavaScript Promise then() ordering

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm still learning JavaScript `Promise`s, and I came across a behavior I don't understand.

```js
var o = $("#output");
var w = function(s) {
    o.append(s + "<br />");
}

var p = Promise.resolve().then(function() {
    w(0);
}).then(function() {
    w(1);
});

p.then(function() {
    w(2);
    return new Promise(function(r) {
        w(3);
        r();
    }).then(function() {
        w(4);
    });
}).then(function() {
    w(5);
});

p.then(function() {
    w(6);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

I would expect these statements to run in order--that is, the that output would be

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Instead, the output is

```
0
1
2
3
6
4
5
```

Even removing the inner `Promise` gives, what seems to me to be, contradicting results.  `1` is output before `2`, but `6` is output before `5`.

Can someone explain this to me?

Something I have noticed is that reassigning `p` each time gives us the order I would expect.

Comment: Why do you expect that order? The order in which you write code isn't necessarily the order in which the promises resolve; only `then` has control over that.

Comment: Because I expect the `then()`s to happen in order.

Comment: Yes, the `then`s of **each** chain of promises.

Comment: I'm confused.  How are the chains created/executed?

Comment: @elclanrs I'm still confused about this.. Based on the accepted answer I would expect 6 to fire before 3?

Comment: @sahbeewah `new Promise` directly calls the function you pass as argument, so no queued jobs can possibly be executed between 2 and 3.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The reason you see `6` early is because you didn't chain, you branched.

When you call `p.then().then().then()`, you've got a chain of promises that *must* execute in the correct order.
However, if you call `p.then().then(); p.then()`, you've got 2 promises attached to `p` - essentially creating a branch, and the 2nd branch will execute along with the first.

You can fix this by ensuring you chain them together `p = p.then().then(); p.then();`

FYI, you almost NEVER want to branch, unless you bring them back together (eg. `Promise.all`), or are intentionally creating a "fire and forget" branch.

Answer (score 4):

What does r() do?

The ordering is indeterminate because you're thenning on the same promise -> this specifically refers to the second and third chain.

If you were doing the following, then order can be guaranteed:

```
var p = Promise.resolve().then(function() {
    w(0);
}).then(function() {
    w(1);
});

// Key difference, continuing the promise chain "correctly".
p = p.then(function() {
    w(2);
    return new Promise(function(r) {
        w(3);
        r();
    }).then(function() {
        w(4);
    });
}).then(function() {
  w(5);
});

p.then(function() {
  w(6);
});
```

Comment: `r()` is just the inner Promise's `resolve()` function.  So am I understanding correctly, that `var p = Promise.resolve(); p.then(f1); p.then(f2);` means that `f1()` and `f2()` will be ordered however the JS engine feels like it?

Comment: @dfoverdx: Yes, `p.then(f); p.then(g)` isn't the same as `p.then(f).then(g)`.

Comment: oh i failed to see that r was the first parameter coming in (I usually type out resolve, reject on created promises myself).

Comment: The ordering is not indeterminate, it is exactly defined in the spec. All then() handlers of a resolved promise are queued for execution in the order of the .then() calls on the promise.

Comment: @Matthijs appears to be correct, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/42360477/5749914.

Answer (score 2):

Let's give every promise and function in your example a name for clarity:

```
var pz = Promise.resolve();
function f0() { w(0); }
var p0 = pz.then(f0);
function f1() { w(1); }
var p1 = p0.then(f1);  // p1 is 'p' in your example

function f2() {
    w(2);
    function f3(resolve_p3) {
        w(3);
        resolve_p3();
    }
    var p3 = new Promise(f3);
    function f4() { w(4); }
    var p4 = p3.then(f4);
    return p4;
}
var p2 = p1.then(f2);
function f5() { w(5); }
var p5 = p2.then(f5);

function f6() { w(6); }
var p6 = p1.then(f6);
```

Let's see what happens step by step. First the top level execution:

- `pz` is fulfilled, hence `pz.then(f0)` immediately queues `f0` for execution, the result of which will resolve `p0`.
- `f1` is scheduled to be queued once `p0` is fulfilled, and the result thereof will resolve `p1`.
- `f2` is scheduled to be queued once `p1` is fulfilled, and the result thereof will resolve `p2`.
- `f5` is scheduled to be queued once `p2` is fulfilled, and the result thereof will resolve `p5`.
- `f6` is scheduled to be queued once `p1` is fulfilled, and the result thereof will resolve `p6`.

Then the queued jobs (initially just `f0`) will be run:

- `f0` is executed: prints "0". `p0` becomes fulfilled, hence `f1` is added to the queue.
- `f1` is executed: prints "1". `p1` becomes fulfilled, hence `f2` and `f6` are added to the queue (in that order). This is the crucial bit, since it means `f6` will be executed before any jobs queued later.
- `f2` is executed: prints "2".
- (inside `f2`): `new Promise` calls `f3`, which prints "3" and fulfills `p3`.
- (inside `f2`): since `p3` is already fulfilled, `f4` is added to the queue, the result of which will resolve `p4`.
- `f2` finally resolves `p2` to `p4`, which means that once `p4` becomes fulfilled, so will `p2`.
- `f6` is executed: prints "6". `p6` becomes fulfilled.
- `f4` is executed: prints "4". `p4` becomes fulfilled. `p2` becomes fulfilled, hence `f5` is added to the queue.
- `f5` is executed: prints "5". `p5` becomes fulfilled.