# Is this Promise chain guaranteed to execute in this order?

Tags: javascript, promise

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

let p = sleep(50);

p.then(() => console.log('a')).then(() => console.log('c'));
p.then(() => console.log('b')).then(() => console.log('d'));
```

Is this guaranteed to print "a, b, c, d" in that order?

As far as I can tell, "a" has to fire before "c" and "b" has to fire before "d", but beyond that, can the JS interpreter decide to execute the remainder in a different order?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Promise then() ordering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111626/javascript-promise-then-ordering)

Comment: `p.then().then()!=p`, but you can cache the first line's "return" to get a guarantee

Comment: @dandavis - thats entirely irrelevant in this context.  Additionally - using != will coerce things.  So its actually impossible to understand what youre trying to convey.

Comment: @TheDembinski: see the possible dupe's answer for details; it's about where, not just when. also, that's psuedocode, though they are both objects anyway... ;)

Comment: @dandavis - I understand now.  Thank you for the note.

Comment: that being said, without errors, i can't think of a case where you wouldn't get `abcd` in a real engine.

Comment: that particular code, using Promise/A+ compliant promises, should output a,b,c,d

Comment: @dandavis - You are correct on all fronts.

Comment: You can rely on c being after a and d being after b.  That will always happen per promise design/specification.  You should NOT rely on the relative ordering of a and b.  It will probably be the case that a is before b because of queuing implementations, but if you want to assure yourself of that, then you should chain b to a so it HAS to come afterwards.  The rule with async operations is that if you need a particular order, then you should create a design that assures that order.

Comment: @GSerg That "dupe" appears to be about OP's misunderstanding that `.then` returns a new Promise. I already discovered that the hard way, now I just want to know if the queuing order is guaranteed by the JS spec.

Comment: The queuing order is noted by the spec. Sources: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Specifications
https://promisesaplus.com/

Comment: @mpen Yes, that OP apparently misunderstood that, but [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29111897/11683) should be correct regardless of their misunderstanding: "the 2nd branch will execute along with the first," with no ordering requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The way that things are queued using `setTimeout` is exactly that - a queue.  If two callbacks are queued with the same 'delay', the callback that was queued first, will fire first.

Edit: I failed to understand the OP's intention initially.

'Branching' promises is what is actually occurring here. Meaning - the 'then-able' being referenced in the first set of then-ables (for a & b) will fire the two provided callbacks at 'the same time' because they both reference the same promise - however - the tricky bit is that they execute in the order that they were queued using the `.then(...)` of the resolving promise object.

Then the following/subsequent callbacks are queued in their respective orders (c & d).

To answer the question directly:  No.  The nature of the async actions in a then-able could be anything.  However, the functions provided in the OP's then-ables are essentially synchronous, resulting in the intuitive - but entirely misleading - logging order.

Comment: I believe the OP is using `setTimeout` as a dummy async function for test purposes, and they are after an answer that concerns `then()`s rather than particularities of `setTimeout`.

Comment: Ah - I believe you are entirely correct.  I will edit my answer to better reflect the nature of the OP.

Comment: @GSerg: That doesn't matter; there is only one async call.

Comment: @SLaks - While I agree with you, I believe that the branching of the then-able (for options a & b) was the actual 'meat' of the question.  I edited my answer to better reflect that idea.  There is ultimately only one async action here resulting in the resolution of the first promise - logging a & b - then ultimately queuing options c & d for execution.

Comment: @GSerg is correct. The `setTimeout` was simply to demonstrate an async call. I am interested in the order of the `then`s assuming all of *those* are synchronous.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I can tell, "a" has to fire before "c" and "b" has to fire before "d"

Yes, that much for certan.

> beyond that, can the JS interpreter decide to execute the remainder in a different order?

Depends on whom you ask, but no there are more guarantees that make the output more predictable:

- the [Promise/A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/) also demands that "*all respective callbacks must execute in the order of their originating calls to then.*" So in your example, that means "a" has to fire before "b", because the callback was chained first to `p`.
- the [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/) defines a job queue for promise callbacks, nailing down the order (imo unnecessarily). It conforms to Promises/A+ in that the "a" and "b" callbacks are queued in the order they were set up when the promise fulfills. It also means that after "a" returns and fulfills the promise, it will schedule "c", and after "b" returns and fulfills the promise, it will schedule "d", so their order is determined as well (for synchronous callbacks).

In general, don't rely on any scheduling algorithm, if you require a certain order then make it explicit.