# In promises, is the callback order guaranteed?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, specifications

I would like to confirm if the call order of callbacks that are passed to `then` is guaranteed when there are several callbacks on the same promise.

This is what I observe. Example:

```
function wait(delayMs) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delayMs))
}

let prom = wait(500)

for (let i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    prom.then(() => { console.log(i) }) // OK: Display 0 to 19 in the right order
```

I observe that the callback order is respected, but I didn't find any documentation on this subject. Is the callback order guaranteed?

***EDIT: It is not a question about how to chain promises. Here I have only one promise with several callbacks. The callbacks are passed to `then` in a determined order. I would like to know if the order of the callback execution is determined too.***

Comment: Question appears to be concerning asynchronous calls within `for` loop rather than "callback order" of `Promise`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Promise then() ordering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111626/javascript-promise-then-ordering)

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate. Please try to understand the subject before to judge it. I added a notice.

Comment: Suren already posted the correct answer: The order is not guaranteed. Maybe it helps to understand the issue you are having when you know that `p.then(f1); p.then(f2);` is not the same as `p.then(f1).then(f2)`.

Comment: @str Can you provide any documentation for your statement?

Comment: _"Here I have only one promise with several callbacks. The callbacks are passed to then"_ Note, `.then()` returns a new `Promise`

Comment: I just want to add that even for the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111626/javascript-promise-then-ordering, the order of resolution is actually deterministic because the chaining is deterministic (due to the fact that they're all "immediate" and in the javascript engine itself).

Comment: @guest271314 Yes the call to `then` provides chained promises that I don't use. They are not in the subject.

Comment: Well, I think I need to clarify. The order of the calls is ordered, but they may run in parallel. For example, the first callback may still run when the last callback was called. So depending on your use case, this may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you call "then" on the same promise multiple times (no chaining), the resolver functions will be called in the same order they were added.

The ECMAScript 2015 specs state that "reactions" are enqueued in insertion order if a promise is resolved.

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-triggerpromisereactions

> **25.4.1.8 TriggerPromiseReactions ( reactions, argument )**
>
> The abstract operation TriggerPromiseReactions takes a collection of PromiseReactionRecords and enqueues a new Job for each record. Each such Job processes the [[Handler]] of the PromiseReactionRecord, and if the [[Handler]] is a function calls it passing the given argument.
>
> 1. Repeat for each reaction in reactions, in original insertion order
>
>    a. Perform EnqueueJob("PromiseJobs", PromiseReactionJob, «‍reaction, argument»).

This means that your resolver functions will be called in the order they were added (in your case, from 0 to 19).

Comment: Yeah! Thank you a lot! You saved me!

Answer (score 3):

From [specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-performpromisethen) :

> If the value of promise's [[PromiseState]] internal slot is "pending",
>
> - Append fulfillReaction as the **last** element of the List that is the value of promise's [[PromiseFulfillReactions]] internal slot.

So yes, by calling multiple time `then()`, you are assured that the callback order will be the same as the one you invoked.

Comment: Thank you a lot too! You saved me too. :)
I desperated to find a valid answer and now I have two. I validated the other but I love you both guys.