# Order of execution of several then() linked to a single promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I have an event handler that process Chrome window events. In order to handle these events, I'm calling async `chrome.windows.get` in a `promise` and using `then()` to process the event.

The problem is when a several `then()` linked to a single promise resolve, their execution order is not the same as the source events order. For example, I'm getting events 1,2 and 3, but execution order could be 3, 2, 1.

I need all `then()` to be executed in the same order as the events came.

Example of simplified code:

```
chromeWinRequests = new Map();

function eventHandler(windowId) {
  if (!chromeWinRequests.has(windowId)) {
    chromeWinRequests.set(windowId, new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       chrome.windows.get(windowId, {populate: true}, (cwin) => {
         if (!chrome.runtime.lastError) {
           resolve(cwin);
         } else {
           reject(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
         }
       });
    }));
  }

  chromeWinRequests.get(windowId).then((cwin) => {
     // process event here
     // when I get here, the source order of events is not preserved
  });
}
```

Is there anything I could do to preserve the processing order?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say you're getting events 1, 2 and 3, where is that in your code?  I don't see that anywhere and thus do not understand the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Promise then() ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111626/javascript-promise-then-ordering)

Comment: answers don't belong in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
chromeWinRequests.get(windowId).then((cwin) => {
    // process event here
    // when I get here, the source order of events is not preserved
});
```

Use `Promise.all` which will make sure all previously collected promises have resolved before getting into the `then` callback. In there you'll need to get the promised value of the one that was created in this context:

```
Promise.all(
    Array.from(chromeWinRequests, ([windowId, promise]) => promise)
).then( (cwins) => {
    const cwin = cwins.pop(); // get the promised value we're interested in
    console.log(cwin);
    // further processing....
});
```

Comment: I had to chain promises instead of having several then() linked to a single promise. The answer has been published. Thank you.

Comment: This is more efficient than chaining. And in the answer you gave yourself, you are *not* chaining the promises in the Map one after the other.

Comment: 1. Regarding your example. I don't have many promises I need to wait for, I just have a single promise and I want all events to be processed after it's resolved. In your example it's waiting for all promises for all windows - that's not what I am looking for.
2. In the solution I published, I'm replacing the first promise with then() promise which will be resolved after the event has been processed. So the next event will be linked not to get() promise, but to then() promise from the previous event.

And indeed, it works, I've checked that.

Comment: If you have "a single promise", how can you be chaining? Your function and map suggests you want to store several promises in the map, and I had understood from your question that you wanted the corresponding `then` callbacks (plural) to execute in the same order as you had stored the promises in your map. Note that my code is not waiting for all promises to resolve: only those that came before, which is exactly what you want to have, because otherwise the `then` callbacks will *not* execute in order. Anyway, if you consider it solved, OK for me. But to me, your question and answer don't match

Answer (score 0):

The question was resolved by changing the last piece of code to the following:

```
newPromise = chromeWinRequests.get(windowId).then((cwin) => {
     // process event here
     return cwin;
});
chromeWinRequests.set(windowId, newPromise);
```

Thanks to [Luizgrs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/912325/luizgrs)

Comment: This makes little sense, since there is no code that uses the new promise, and so it is equivalent to what you already had.

Comment: New upcoming event uses the new promise, so they are linked into a chain.

Comment: That is what you say, but it is nowhere in your solution. What you have written here is just adding one more `then` to the promise you store in the map, nothing more. So that does not change a thing. If you have a solution, it is not this part of the code that does the trick.